# How can i open sublime text editor with terminal on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: terminal

I want open sublime text editor via terminal, already i can it open via `subl` command, but problem is when i open editor then terminal loading like as below

```
(sublime_text:7397): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 28147 was not found when attempting to remove it

(sublime_text:7397): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 28265 was not found when attempting to remove it

(sublime_text:7397): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 28323 was not found when attempting to remove it

(sublime_text:7397): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 28383 was not found when attempting to remove it

(sublime_text:7397): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 28439 was not found when attempting to remove it

(sublime_text:7397): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 28502 was not found when attempting to remove it

(sublime_text:7397): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 28564 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

I want both working sublime text and with terminal, how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
subl &
```

The "&" sign cause the process to be detached from the parent process, which in your case is the opened terminal.

Comment: I want open any directory with `subl` command when need this directory open with sublime work

Comment: ן didn't understand your comment. how can you open a directory with sublime ?

Comment: yes and When i'll press key with `cntl+c` via terminal then my open directory close that is i don't want, i want when i'll press `cntl+c` then still open this directory with command line or terminal for another process..